# How to capture photo when a face detected smiles using Ionic?

Tags: computer-vision, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, face-recognition, ionic-native

Using Ionic, is it possible for me to be able to capture an image and the trigger would be whenever the face smiles? I am looking for suggestions, any resource materials that I could get using Ionic.

Comment: Please help, my deadline is for the week and my boss occasionally walks behind me with a gun.

Comment: This isn't easy, I think you'd need to write your own native plugin for this, did you promise this to your gun wielding boss already? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some emotion detection api. This problem is not related to ionic itself but to computer vision. So what you likely do is send/upload your photo to online api (for example google cloud vision or any other) to detect emotions in your photo and it will detect emotions for for you. The result will be then utilized by your application.

Comment: What I was trying to do is that I need to use the facial recognition as a trigger to take the photo, not to use the photo to be sent to an http/api. I understand your answer is possible but it doesn't solve my problem, which is to use a facial recognition API to trigger the camera to capture the photo.

Comment: Fortunately, they decided to implement this as native. I really appreciate it. Thanks!